# glfwSwapBuffers() and vertical refresh on Windows

Tags: windows, opengl, glfw

I want to do something that is very trivial with OpenGL and GLFW: I want to scroll a 100x100 white filled rectangle from left to right and back again. The rectangle should be moved by 1 pixel per frame and the scrolling should be perfectly smooth. This is my code:

```c
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    int i = 0, mode = 0;

    if(!glfwInit()) return -1;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if(!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 640, 0, 480, -1, 1);     
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);    
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);   
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glRecti(i, 190, i + 100, 290);      

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

        if(!mode) {
            i++;
            if(i >= 539) mode = 1;
        } else {
            i--;
            if(i <= 0) mode = 0;
        }           
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

On Mac OS X and Linux this code is working really fine. The scrolling is perfectly sync'ed with the vertical refresh and you cannot see any stuttering or flickering. It is really perfectly smooth.

On Windows, things are more difficult. By default, `glfwSwapInterval(1)` doesn't have any effect on Windows when desktop compositing is enabled. GLFW docs say that this has been done because enabling the swap interval with DWM compositing enabled can lead to severe jitter. This behaviour can be changed by compiling GLFW with `GLFW_USE_DWM_SWAP_INTERVAL` defined. In that case, the code above works really fine on Windows as well. The scrolling is perfectly sync'ed and there is no jitter. I tested it on a variety of different machines running XP, Vista, 7, and 8.

However, there has to be a very good reason that made the GLFW authors disable the swap interval on Windows by default so I suppose that there are many configurations where it will indeed lead to severe jitter. Maybe I was just lucky that none of my machines showed it. So defining `GLFW_USE_DWM_SWAP_INTERVAL` is not really a solution I can live with because there has to be a reason why it is disabled by default, although it somewhat escapes me that the GLFW team didn't come up with a nicer solution because as it stands now, GLFW programs aren't really portable because of this issue. Take the code above as an example: It will be perfectly sync'ed on Linux and OS X, but on Windows it will run at lightning speed. This somewhat defies GLFW's concept of portability in my eyes.

Given the situation that `GLFW_USE_DWM_SWAP_INTERVAL` cannot be used on Windows because the GLFW team explicitly warns about its use, I'm wondering what else I should do. The natural solution is of course a timer which measures the time and makes sure that `glfwSwapBuffers()` is not called more often than the monitor's vertical refresh rate.

However, this also is not as simple as it sounds since I cannot use `Sleep()` because this would be much too imprecise. Hence, I'd have to use a polling loop with `QueryPerformanceCounter()`. I tried this approach and it pretty much works but the CPU usage is of course up to 100% now because of the polling loop sleep. When using `GLFW_USE_DWM_SWAP_INTERVAL`, on the other hand, CPU usage is at a mere 1%.

An alternative would be to set up a timer that fires at regular intervals but AFAIK the precision of `CreateTimerQueueTimer()` is not very satisfying and probably doesn't yield perfectly sync'ed results.

To cut a long story short: I'd like to ask what is the recommended way of dealing with this problem? The example code above is of course just for illustration purposes. My general question is that I'm looking for a clean way to make `glfwSwapBuffers()` swap buffers in sync with the monitor's vertical refresh on Windows. On Linux and Mac OS X this is already working fine but on Windows there is the problem with severe jitter that the GLFW docs talk about (but which I don't see here).

I'm still somewhat puzzled that GLFW doesn't provide an inbuilt solution to this problem and pretty much leaves it up to the programmer to workaround this. I'm still a newbie to OpenGL but from my naive point of view, I think that having a function that swaps buffers in sync with vertical refresh is a feature of fundamental importance so it escapes me why GLFW doesn't have it on Windows.

So once again my question is: How can I workaround the problem that `glfwSwapInterval()` doesn't work correctly on Windows? What is the suggested approach to solve this problem? Is there a nicer way than using a poll timer that will hog the CPU?

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue has solved itself by a strange coincidence in timing. [This commit](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/commit/8309e0ecb09fe5cf670dff5df1e7ca71821c27bd) has been added to GLFW's master branch just a few days ago, and it is *removing* the `GLFW_USE_DWM_SWAP_INTERVAL` because they are now using DWM's [DWMFlush()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to do the syncing when DWM is in use. The changelog for this commit includes:

> - [Win32] Removed `GLFW_USE_DWM_SWAP_INTERVAL` compile-time option
> - [Win32] Bugfix: Swap interval was ignored when DWM was enabled

So probably grabbing the newest git HEAD for GLFW is all you need to do.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this but it doesn't work well for me in fullscreen mode. Graphics are smooth and perfectly sync'ed in windowed mode but in fullscreen mode the moving white rectangle really stutters. I've already let them know yesterday here: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/24  (my nickname is softwarefailure)

Comment: Well, in fullscreen mode, compositing is usually bypassed.

Comment: What does that mean? I can see here that glfwIsCompositionEnabled() still returns TRUE when in fullscreen mode. This means that glfwSwapInterval() isn't working in fullscreen mode either with the old GLFW 3.1.1. With the new fix in the master branch I get stuttery graphics with the example posted above. You can clearly see the rectangle stuttering when moving.

Comment: `DwmFlush` is now only used in windowed mode.